# Какая система контроля версий больше всего подходит для новичка?

Tags: веб-программирование, контроль-версий

Планирую освоить работу с системами контроля версий. Git показался сложен(( Какие есть более упрощенные системы? Преимущественно планирую работать в одиночку

Comment: Попробуйте еще hg (mercury), svn (subversion)

Comment: Где же любители hg, prefoce и bazzar?

Comment: Каким бы git не показался, а знать его надо.

Comment: Про darcs с его алгеброй патчей никто даже не вспомнил :)

Comment: Любопытно:

[http://githowto.com/ru](http://githowto.com/ru)

    Git
    — мощная и сложная распределенная система контроля версий. Понимание всех возможностей git открывает для разработчика новые горизонты в управлении исходным кодом.

[http://svnhowto.com/](http://svnhowto.com/)

    SVN
    — мощная и свободная централизованная система управления  версиями. Понимание всех возможностей SVN открывает для разработчика новые горизонты в управлении исходным кодом.

Comment: @avp: проверил только что: до сих пор те же строки с разницей в одно слово. Интересно, почему же все-таки Git — сложная система, а SVN — свободная?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для работы в одиночку svn вполне подходит. Он гораздо проще git'а в использовании и этим очень подкупает. Но новичку я бы его не посоветовал. Наоборот, даже запретил бы. Дело в том, что svn калечит мозг. Он вырабатывает у человека плохие повадки. Я много раз видел людей, которые, перейдя с svn'а на git, не могли по-настоящему насладиться возможностями этой полноценной системы управления версиями. В git'е они работали так, как будто это был svn. С людьми происходит примерно то же, о чём говорил Дейкстра, когда высказывался за запрет изучения Бейсика в школах. Согласно ему, нужно защитить детей от разрушающего влияния простоты Бейсика. После того, как они учатся программировать на Бейсике, их почти невозможно научить нормально программировать ни на одном настоящем языке.

Тем не менее, если git всё-таки покажется слишком сложным и перебороть в себе этот ложный страх (у которого глаза велики) не удастся, то есть система попроще - [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/). Для одиночной работы она подходит чуть более, чем полностью. Кроме того, она сразу приучает к правильным вещам - заводить тикеты и поддерживать в актуальном состоянии wiki. Обе эти функции встроены прямо в саму систему управления версиями. Её автором, так же, как и в случае с git'ом, является человек далеко не случайный - разработчик SQLite.

Comment: @Shamov, а Вы реально (несколько раз в неделю) используете что-то, кроме тривиальных update чужих кусков и commit своих?

IMHO в *правильной команде* (в фазе активной разработки) один файл не меняется несколькими людьми.

Comment: @avp, ну как бы файл проекта с добавлением новых файлов запросто могут поменяться несколькими людьми одновременно + всякая фигня которую используют многие части системы типа настроек, это на вскидку.

Comment: @avp Да, реально. Может и не несколько раз в неделю, но достаточно часто. Я очень люблю бранчи.  Код, который ещё не отлажен или даже не до конца сделан, у меня живёт только в них.

Comment: @aknew, может конечно, но в SVN-то какая с этим проблема?

Comment: @avp это было к тезису "в правильной команде (в фазе активной разработки) один файл не меняется несколькими людьми."

Comment: @aknew, а в правильной команде есть человек (руководитель разработки), который отвечает за общие файлы системы и правит их (обычно) только он.

Comment: это как заведено и смотря какой уровень. На практике я сталкивался и с описанной вами системой, и с тем что каждый может править при условии что приоритет у изменений из репозитория

Comment: солидарен с автором поста, что лучше начинать пусть и со сложного, но все же правильного решения.. сам имею не малый опыт общения с svn git и hg , у всех имеются как плюсы так и минусы ( на вкус и цвет ). svn имхо это тоже самое что копировать папку проекта в папку бекапов и подписывать датой только через интернет ( без инета тут ни как ).. git и hg во многом очень похожи, но не во всем ( например branch'и ). предпочтение отдал git, но по работе приходится пользоваться hg . по git в сети есть русскоязычная книга http://git-scm.com/book/ru

Answer (score 6):

А чем git оказался сложен? У [github](https://github.com/) есть свой клиент, который все изменения отслеживает и предлагает их закоммитить... осваивается очень просто.

И что значит "освоить"? Почитайте доки ([git howto на русском](http://githowto.com/ru)), там все просто даже из консоли. освоился за полчаса-час.

Вы можете сами у себя на машине поднять систему конроля версий например [scm manager](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/Home), она поддерживает и svn и git и mercurial и вы сможете оценить и работу с каждой из версий, после чего выбрать наиболее удобную для себя.

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Рискуя быть ретроградом, я все таки выступлю против Git'а в данном контексте. Git больше подходит для больших (реально больших проектов), когда над проектом работает несколько команд (не несколько разработчиков, а именно команд разработчиков). Git это как известно распределенный VCS и там хорошо реализовано управление ветками (branch).

Текущий опыт управления исходниками Linux/Android именно под Git как раз и свидетельствует в пользу его преимуществ именно в больших проектах.

SVN хорош, очень хорош. Причем хорош везде не только в мелких проектах, но и в больших тоже. Поработав и под тем и под другим VCS, я не обнаружил, например, в Git'е так любимого мной глобального Revision #, в противовес Git предлагает SHA-1 сигнатуру ветки, которой очень неудобно пользоваться. Различий, конечно, много. Много не только в деталях, но и в идеологии.

Ну а утверждения г-на [@Shamov](/users/8566/shamov)'а об уродстве SVN я бы отнес больше к очередному холивару, нежели к реальному положению вещей :)

Comment: Когда я говорил о том, что svn калечит мозг, я имел в виду именно вот это нездоровое пристрастие к глобальному номеру ревизии, а точнее к наличию главной ветки - trunk'а.

Comment: А кому мешает trunk?

Comment: svn хорош например для контроля версий медиа файлов. С ними в git тяжело, так как репозиторий в какой то момент начинает весь гигабайты. @Shamov совершено прав, svn маленький уродец, который хорош пока ты не начинаешь бренчиватся. Тут не холивара ради, посмотрите презенташку Линуса в гугле где он рассказывать про git.

Comment: еще свн хорош тем что можно юзать только ту папку т.к. для него это все отдельные сущности и в каждой папке есть метаданные, а вот с гитом такой фокус не пройдет

Comment: @rnd_d Вы, кстати, пробовали бранчеваться в `Subversion` или сделали такой вывод только на основании выступления Линуса?

Comment: @Shamov Как система с `revnum` связана с `trunk'ом`? И чем, по-вашему, `trunk` концептуально отличается от `master`?

Comment: Использование revnum - это надёжный признак того, что в репозитории существует одна главная ветка, которая не позволит из одного репозитория сделать два и более, сохранив связь между ними. А это в свою очередь превращает бранчинг в лучшем случае в профанацию идеи, в худшем - в геморрой. Концептуальное отличие trunk'а от master'а в том, что первый глобально главный, а второй - локально.

Comment: @Shamov все зависит от того, что считать бранчем. Если под бранчем понимается некая работа которая должна быть слита в главный ствол то это один подход (а ля svn), а если это кусок который вечно будет параллельно расти основному стволу имея с ним какие-то общие куски - то это идеология гита.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, до гита сидел 2 года на svn. Пробовал бренчиватся. Получилось, но приятного в этом мало.

Comment: `svn revnum` прекрасно заменяется на выхлоп `git describe`.

А работать с DAG (git, mercurial) вместо линейного списка намного удобнее. С SVN немного работал, и там делать сильно переплетенные feature branches тоже можно, но далеко не так приятно — после каждой реинтеграции надо было пересоздавать бранч (дело было давно, еще с 1.4). Сейчас, вроде, все проще там, но уже привык к workflow'у с возможностью коммитить локально, на каждый чих «попробую так» лепить ветку, не стесняться amend'ить по «черновому» коду, а push'ить уже разумно чистую историю.

Comment: Алсо, у меня сейчас в git'е репозиторий с кодом одной и той же системы, которая задеплоена в двух разных организациях. У каждой организации свои 2 бранча (development и production), специфичные функции обычно пишутся в них (но частенько и cherry-pick'аются от «соседей»), общие — в master. Я не уверен, что с SVN такой workflow будет получится без танцев с бубном. В trunk-то, пишут, до сих пор [бубен нужен](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309602/subversion-branch-reintegration-in-v1-6).

Comment: @aknew svn начиная с версии 1.7 уже не мусорит каталогами .svn по всему дереву — там теперь как и в git — только один служебный каталог.

Answer (score 4):

Мое ИМХО, учить все равно придется и гит, и свн хотя бы основы т.к. оба они де факто стандарты и с ними обязательно столкнешься в разработке если не в своей конторе, то с примерами со стороны точно. Я, правда, прикладной программист, но не думаю что в данном аспекте это важно

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте svn - это классика жанра!

Answer (score 2):

Ну и насчёт git`а. 
Для удобство использования, если не нравиться консоль есть Git GUI.
Вот набор различных фронтендов: 
[набор Фронтендов для GUI интерфейса git](http://the-bosha.ru/2010/05/11/nebolshoy-obzor-gui-interfeisov-dlya-git/)

Кстати вот ещё ссылка на небольшой видео урок (на англ). Там достаточно ясно показана простота работы в Git`e из консоли. 
[Видеоурок № 1 по Git](http://clck.ru/3s3WD)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посоветовал попробовать и Git(Bitbuckets, GitHub) и SVN.
Во-первых, когда учишься работать и с тем, и с другим получаешь величественный и неповторимый опыт, знание, умение, а также навыки свободного, быстро перехода. В дальнейшем  без этих систем уже будет никак и многие люди, которые говорят "Ай, это сложно, лучше попробую что по-легче, простенькое" в дальнейшем сталкиваются с проблемой перехода на сложное, тратят свое время на изучение, а именно то время, которое можно было потратить ранее и уже пользоваться всеми полученными навыками. 
Если вы пишете под Java из под Eclipse есть хороший набор для разработчика под Git. Вам будет абсолютно необязательно использовать GitHub начинку и все остальное. Вы в полной мере можете ощутить всю прелесть развития Вашего потенциала. 
Во-вторых, попробуйте сами разобраться. Ведь так много статей на Хабре и в других места, позволяющих понять все прелести и разновидности систем контроля версий. Если Вы сами вникните в данный вопрос, попробуете на практике, сами столкнетесь с трудными местами, потратите несколько дней, то в дальнейшем Вам уже не придется изучать, сравнивать и копаться в тонне книг по SVn & Git.

Надеюсь, помог советом, остальное, конечно же, в Ваших руках.
С уважением, Евгений.

Answer (score 1):

Я работаю на Windows, пробовал SVN, Git для одиночной разработки - чисто для себя. Но всё было не то что надо, и быстро забивал. Пока не попробовал Mercurial. Офигенная вещь как минимум для разработки в одиночку для себя. За пол года работы не раз мне помогала.

Тем более есть Bitbuckets.

Answer (score 1):

Если будете осваивать Subversion — почитайте книгу «[Управление версиями в Subversion](http://svnbook.org/)» — http://svnbook.org/. Книга частично переведена на русский язык.

Answer (score 0):

SVN — классика жанра. Имею мнение, что начинать надо с него.